# GenyMotion GAPPS - Failed to flash file nougat

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I get this error:

[image]

I downloaded it from here [opengapps.org](http://opengapps.org) with these settings:

[image]

How can I solve this? I'm using a Nexus 6P on Nougat. What do I do wrong? Did I get the wrong file?

**Note** that the questions that are like mine are ***Waay*** too localized. (The answers are only links to a specific archive for a different android version/device)